# How to Ensure Uninterrupted Streaming with OpenAI's Chat Completion API and handle Disconnects After Answer Delivery

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

In my application, I'm using two OpenAI APIs: Chat Completion API with streaming and Chat Completion API without streaming. The streaming API is accessible at `@app.post('chat/completion/stream')`,
and the non-streaming API is available at `@app.post('/chat/completion')`.

When I initiate the streaming API, it sends tokens one by one, but I've noticed interruptions when I make a call to the non-streaming API during a streaming session. Interruptions such as waiting for the non-streaming api to serve the request and the continue streaming (Where it left off).  Sometimes, the streaming gets dropped after a long pause. I want to ensure uninterrupted streaming if a streaming call is initiated and handle disconnections after answer delivery.

Here's the issue I'm facing:

`First Issue - Streaming Interruptions:`
I initiate the streaming API, which starts sending tokens one by one.
The structure of the tokens looks like this:

> b'{"token": " directly", "isFinish": "False", "isAnswer": "True"}'

`What I'm Looking For:`

I want to ensure that once streaming starts, it should continue uninterrupted until it is finished. Is there a way to achieve this?

`Second Issue - Disconnect After Answer Delivery:`

When I call the non-streaming Chat Completion API and it delivers the answers, I get to see the status message in the terminal:

```
     INFO: 172.17.0.1:62064 - "POST /chat/v4?org_id=129332 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

However, in the case of streaming, I don't receive such a status message. Nevertheless, the next request is still getting processed.

`What i am looking for:`

Is it possible to implement a mechanism to disconnect after the answer is delivered when using the streaming Chat Completion API?. I doubt the connection is still active with the previous client.

I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure uninterrupted streaming and manage disconnections after answer delivery when using OpenAI's Chat Completion APIs. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

`Code`

## Chat completion with streaming.

---

```
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

@app.post('chat/completion/stream')
async def answer_using_streaming(
            query:ChatQuestion,
            community_id: int =  Query(alias='community_id')):
    
    ask_gpt = Ask()
    
    return  StreamingResponse(
        ask_gpt.ask_stream(
            question=query.q,
            community_id=406),
            media_type='application/json')




Class Ask:
    
        def ask_stream(self, question, community_id) -> dict:

            // fetch content from vector db for the respective question

        
            sess = requests.Session()
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': OpenAIChatConfig.content_type,
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {OpenAIChatConfig.authorization}',
                'OpenAI-Organization': OpenAIChatConfig.org_id
            }

            query_data = {
                'model': AskConfig.model,
                'messages': [{'role': 'user', 'content': final_context}],
                'temperature': 0,
                'stream': True
            }

            with sess.post(OpenAIChatConfig.url, headers=headers, json=query_data, stream=True) as resp:
               
                
                for line in resp.iter_lines():
                    if line:
                        data = line.decode('utf-8')
                        data = data.replace("data: ", "")

                        try:
                            delta = json.loads(data)['choices'][0]['delta']

                            if delta.get('content', None) != None:
                                
                                yield json.dumps(
                                    {'token': delta_content, "isSources": "False", "isFinish": "False",
                                     "isAnswer": "True"})

                        except Exception as e:
                            if '[DONE]' in data:
                                is_done = True
                            else:
                                pass

                if is_done:
                    yield json.dumps({'token': 'Done', "isSources": "False", "isFinish": "False", "isAnswer": "True"})
```

### Chat completion

```
@app.post('/chat/completion')
async def fetch_answer(
            query:ChatQuestion,
            community_id: int =  Query(alias='community_id')):

    logger.debug(f'Hit API ASK point for thread {thread_id}')
    response = await fetchInformationFromMilvus(
                    community_id=community_id, 
                    question=query.q)

    return response


async def fetchInformationFromMilvus(community_id,question):
    try:
        return ask_gpt.ask(question=question,community_id=community_id)
    except Exception as e:
        return {'response':False,'question':question}


Class Ask:

    def ask(self, question, community_id) -> dict:
        
        # fetch the content from vector DB.

        data = self.query_chat_gpt(final_context) # get the response from gpt

        // process the response 

        return response

    

    def query_chat_gpt(self, content, config=OpenAIChatConfig):

        try:

            headers = {
                'Content-Type': config.content_type,
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {config.authorization}',
                'OpenAI-Organization': config.org_id
            }

            query_data = {
                'model': AskConfig.model,
                'messages': [{'role': 'user', 'content': content}],
                'temperature': 0
            }

            response = requests.post(config.url, headers=headers, json=query_data)
            response_json = response.json()
            return response_json['choices'][0]['message'].get('content', '')
        except Exception as e:
            return ''
```